# Log Analytics API does not show in the AAD registered app API list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, logging, azure-api-management, azure-log-analytics

I'm using Azure Log Analytics to write application logs to it, like trace and error logs and also audit logs.
I would need to be able to query this log data in my web application in a flexible way (no static searches), so I came up to their REST API, like described here:
https://dev.loganalytics.io/

For some reason the authentication for query the data is different than inserting new data to the log, which I already did successfully with building a signature using the workspace id and key.

According to the documentation when using the search API I need to register my app with their AAD service, so I tried to follow the steps described in here:
https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/Authorization/AAD-Setup

My log analytics registration:
[Log analytics registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX8pK.png)

So I tried to create the app registration and tried to add permissions:
[App Registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlip4.png)

And then I want to choose "Log Analytics" in the API access - but "Log Analytics" is not listed there!
As can see in this image:
[API List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp20D.png)

Why Log Analytics is not listed here? Am I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **search for Log Analytics API in the "Select an API" menu**, then you could see this. It is not in the default list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when I do a search for "Log Analytics" (also tried "Log Analytics AP" and "Log Analytics API") it shows "No Results" for me..

Comment: Do you execute this `New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId ca7f3f0b-7d91-482c-8e09-c5d840d0eac5 -DisplayName "Log Analytics API"` firstly? You need create the service firstly.

Comment: I suggest you could refer this [link](https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/Authorization/AAD-Setup) step by step.

Comment: Okay that was the problem .. I didn't know that I have to do that step before. Thank you!